# How can I transcribe a Voice Memo to Text?

Tags: text, voice-dictation, voice-memo

I need to transcribe Voice Memo recording to text. Can I play the recording and use Dictation? is there another method to convert an existing Voice Memo to text?

Comment: My Google Voice does that :) , but it is not very accurate :(

Answer (score 2):

I would try using [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/soundflower-landing-page/), which allows one to virtually plug your sound output to input, and then use Dictation.